# Tiling a domed roof?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, transforms

What is the best way tile the dome using these tiles? I'm trying to do it by using the curve modifier while changing rotation on the x axis but it's taking forever to get it right. Do I just need to try harder or is there a better way?[image]

Comment: if your tiles have all the same size, I guess it's the solution, it should not take forever though

Comment: You can also try the instancing. May be you have to modify the topology of the sphere. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/index.html

Comment: are you open for add-on - solutions like sverchok, animation nodes?

Answer (score 4):

If you are open to use sverchok...it is pretty easy.

Use this node setup:

[image]

and you get this if you are changing the factor:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The [Tissue](https://github.com/alessandro-zomparelli/tissue) shipped with Blender might be well suited for this if I understood correctly.

Enabled it in the Add-on preferences.

[image]

Create a mesh object of one tile, select it then select the dome object. Go to the Edit panel in the N Panel and click on Tesselate.

[image]

You can tweak the default settings but it should be good to go already. Click on OK to tesselate the mesh. You may have to rotate the tile mesh in edit mode if the orientation is not right.

This will create a new object with the tesselated mesh.

[image]

Or

[image]

I don't think you can change the settings so the tiles are offset like in a regular roof. You can do it a number of different ways with a few steps but I'll show this one :

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + click then <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + click on alternative face rings and type <kbd>Y</kbd> or go into Mesh > Split > Selection to make the faces stand alone.

[image]

Then rotate half a vertical ring along Z. This can be eye-balled if precision isn't an issue, otherwise it can be deducted by dividing 360° by the number of vertical rings then dividing by 2 again.

[image]

Finally, go back to the first steps to tesselate the mesh :

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to  offset per row. (akin to roof tiles)?

Comment: @batFINGER updated answer, I don't know of a one click solution but there might one :)